# Any available frameworks for SIP for iphone?

Tags: ios, implementation, sip

Im supposed to use SIP for my application. I went through some documentation regarding SIP like ietf-sip-documentation , siphon , linphone for iphone and ipod. But nowhere they have mentioned about any available frameworks or any such a thing for implementation part. There are lot of things that are yet unsettling to me about SIP. I would love to get a little more clarity on this. Any help would be appreciated.

**EDIT:** I would want to know whether there are any frameworks available for ios or should we create our own classes for the interface?

Thanks

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Session_Initiation_Protocol ????

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doubango framework http://doubango.org/ / https://code.google.com/p/doubango/ also does a nice job here. C-based, so you would probably like to do your own Objective-C wrappers.

Comment: actually they have objective c wrappers too.. ios-ngn-stack

Comment: Well, my answer was obviously about version 1.0 (3 years ago) and not about the more recent 2.0 and I am not sure about the license back then. But I know for sure that the guy / company behind the framework was offering commercial licensing as well as consulting services around the framework.

Answer (score 2):

How about [resiprocate](http://www.resiprocate.org/Main_Page) or [PJSIP](http://www.pjsip.org)? Both can be compiled for iOS. Do you also need RTP and media handling? If so, PJSIP has that built in as well.

Comment: PJSIP seems interesting.. will go through it and see if i can use it

Comment: @mattjgalloway : Can you please provide some more details about resiprocate? Like how to use it for ios ?

Comment: @i-droid have you tried compiling it yet? Basically just compile it and use it.

Comment: @mattjgalloway: Yes sir,I am trying to compile it from many days but unable to compile. Can you provide me the steps which you have followed?

Comment: Plus one for resiprocate - it is BSD.